# Retornar números de uma String

Tags: java

Sou programador `PHP` e dando manutenção em um projeto `Java` me vi com a necessidade de retornar apenas números contidos em uma determinada `String`.

Não encontrei perguntas a respeito disso no SOpt e encontrei no SOen, por isso trago aqui essa questão buscando saber qual é a melhor opção, visto que em `Java` por ser uma linguagem de mais baixo nível, tudo ou quase tudo faz diferença no processamento e sempre pode ser otimizado...

Um exemplo do que estou solicitando:

```
String cnpj = "83.411.122/0001-06";
```

O retorno esperado:

```
"83411122000106"
```

Comment: Você pode nos dar um exemplo do que você quer dizer com "[...] retornar apenas números em uma determinada `String`"? Em um assunto paralelo Java é uma linguagem comercial, está bem longe de ser de baixo nível.

Comment: Ok, vamos esclarecer as coisas, Baixo Nível, significa que ela tem mais poder sobre o hardware, mais capacidade de manipula-lo, em segundo lugar, colocarei um exemplo do que estou sugerindo, desculpe por não ser exatamente claro, amigo.

Comment: @Genos, creio que tenha ficado mais claro agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução encontrada no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030936/2072674):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Comment: Nesse caso ele também poderia usar expressão regulares para encontrar apenas os números da variável `String` e depois retornar o que tivesse entrado, certo?

Comment: Desculpe @R.Santos, não entendi bem a sua pergunta, nesse caso o `replaceAll` com a Expressão Regular já retorna o String somente com os números...

Comment: É que quando usei expressões regulares, eu utilizava `matcher` e `pattern` para estipular padrões de o que eu gostaria de selecionar em um texto, nesse caso seria criar uma expressões regular que procurasse apenas números, e que depois de analisar a `String` me retornasse o que havia sido encontrado